# Book where everyone has magic and has to undertake a test where they create a monster

Tags: story-identification

I'm trying to find a book where everyone had magical abilities of some sort. They had to take a test that I think involves fear or creating some kind of monster. I think there are different levels and the test is how they put everyone on a level.

It involved a school for kids with magical abilities.

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.